# ActivityIndicator set color doesn't work on IPad mini

Tags: react-native

It still shows default color white no matter what I change for balck or red.

I test it on android and iphone simulator is working.

Any one has any suggestion ? Thanks in advance.

"react-native": "0.57.8",

```
<ActivityIndicator color="#0000CC" size="large" animating={true} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without animating={true}

```
<ActivityIndicator color="#0000CC" size="large" />
```

Animating somtimes dsnt work for all devices.
Also if you can, share your full code.

Make sure ActivityIndicator is inside a view.

You're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for reply, remove `animating={true}` still doesn't work.  I'm sure `ActivityIndicator` is inside a view, because I can see the white spinner even I set the color is `color="black"`